# Loading an entity into a field depending on the choice in another field Symfony PRE_SET_DATA Event Listener

Tags: php, forms, symfony, entity

Hi i got my OrderType form.

Here is my code:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
   $builder
              ->add('client', EntityType::class, array(
              'data' => $options['client'],
              'mapped' => false,
              'attr' => ['class' => 'chosen-select','data-placeholder'=>'Wybierz klienta'],
              'class' => UserDetails::class,
              'choice_label' => function ($client) {
              return  ''.$firma.' '.$client->getJson()["client"]["imie"] .' '. $client->getJson()["client"]["nazwisko"].'';
               },
              'label' => 'Wybierz klienta'))


               ->add('save', SubmitType::class, [
               'label' => 'Zapisz',
               'attr' => ['class' => 'btn btn-primary pull-right']]) ;

    $builder->addEventListener( 
              FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA,
                function (FormEvent $event) {
                       $form = $event->getForm();
                       $client =$form->get('client')->getData();
                       $shipping = null === $client ? array() : $client->getClientsShippings()->getJson()["clients_shippings"]["name"];

           $form->add('shipping', EntityType::class, array(
               'class' => ClientsShippings::class,
               'placeholder' => '',
               'choices' => $shipping));
             }
           );
}
```

There are no errors, but nothing happens either. I do not know how to achieve that, after selecting the EventListener client, PRE_SET_DATA loaded the shipping addresses assigned to the client in the ClientsShippings entity depending on the chosen client.
I read this one a few times on symfony.com, but I can not completely understand these events.

Could someone help me run it, let me have an example of how it works. Maybe I think about it completely in a different way.

---

```
  public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
                ->add('client', EntityType::class, array(
    'data' => $options['client'],
    'mapped' => false,
    'attr' => ['class' => 'chosen-select','data-placeholder'=>'Wybierz klienta'],
    'class' => UserDetails::class,
    'choice_label' => function ($client) {
      if(isset($client->getJson()["client"]["firma"]))
      {
        $firma = $client->getJson()["client"]["imie"];
        }
        else {
          $firma = "";
          }
    return  ''.$firma.' '.$client->getJson()["client"]["imie"] .' '. $client->getJson()["client"]["nazwisko"].'';
      },
    'label' => 'Wybierz klienta'

                ))

        ->add('product', EntityType::class, array(
    'data' => $options['product'],
    'mapped' => false,
    'multiple' => true,
    'class' => Products::class,
    'attr' => ['class' => 'chosen-select','data-placeholder'=>'Wybierz produkt'],
    'choice_label' => function ($product) {
        return  ''.$product->getJson()["products"]["name"] .' | Stan Magazynowy: '.$product->getJson()["products"]["stock"].'';
      },
  'label' => 'Wybierz produkty'

        ))

            ->add('save', SubmitType::class, [
            'label' => 'Zapisz',
            'attr' => ['class' => 'btn btn-primary pull-right']])
        ;

    $builder->get('client')->addEventListener(
      FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT,
      function (FormEvent $event)
      {
        $form = $event->getForm();

        $form->getParent()->add('shipping', EntityType::class, [
          'class' => ClientsShippings::class,
          'placeholder' => 'Wybierz adres dostawy',
          'choices' => $form->getData()->getclientsShippings()
        ]);
      }
    );


    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Symfony form has 2 main usages:

1. Creating a new entity (`Form::submit()` is called)
2. Editing an existing entity (`Form::setData()` and `Form::Submit()` are called)

**Note:** In both cases, `Form::handleRequest()` is called before `Form::submit()` to check if the request can be submitted or not.

We have 2 main category of form events:

- events during pre-populating forms (used only for edit entity form)
- events during form submission (used for both new and edit entity forms)

## 1. Pre-populating the form with model data

**PRE_SET_DATA**

The `PRE_SET_DATA` event, gets the value of data that you're starting with (`Order` object in your case), and gets dispatched right before the form is populated with the data of entity object.

You may use this event to:

- Modify the form data during population
- Add or Remove form fields

**POST_SET_DATA**

This event is fired right after the `Form::setData()` method is called and can be use to:

- Read the data, after pre-populating the form

Both `POST_SET_DATA` and `POST_SET_DATA` events are dispatched during pre-populating form data.

## 2. Form Submission

**PRE_SUBMIT**

This is fired when `Form::submit()` or `Form::handleRequest()` are called. This event can be used to:

- Change the data captured from the request
- Add or remove fields before submitting the data

**SUBMIT**

This event is dispatched after `PRE_SUBMIT` and during `Form::submit` (after the model and view data normalization, and before denormalization). You may use this event to:

- Change the data after normalization.

**POST_SUBMIT**
this event is dispatched after the `Form::submit()`. You may use this event to:

- Fetch the data after denormalization.

## Answering your question

You should use 2 event listeners, one for `PRE_SET_DATA` and one for `POST_SUBMIT`:

**OrderType**

```
class OrderType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('client', EntityType::class, array(
                'class' => UserDetails::class
            ))
            ->add('save', SubmitType::class)
        ;
    
        $modifier = function (FormInterface $form, Client $client = null) {
            $shippings = null === $client ? array() : $client->getClientsShippings();

            $form->add('shipping', EntityType::class, array(
                'class' => ClientsShippings::class,
                'choices' => $shippings,
            ));
        };

        $builder->addEventListener(
            FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA,
            function (FormEvent $event) use ($modifier) {
                $orderData = $event->getData();
                $modifier($event->getForm(), $orderData->getClient());
            }
        );

        $builder->get('client')->addEventListener(
            FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT,
            function (FormEvent $event) use ($modifier) {
                $client = $event->getForm()->getData();
                $modifier($event->getForm()->getParent(), $client);
            }
        );
    }
}
```

You should also make an AJAX call (some JavaScript) to update the `shipping` list, according to the selected client.

Comment: :) ok, it is even possible to get dynamically change values of input field depence on what we choosen in first input ?

Comment: ok i understand now how it works, but why now if i do example POST_SUBMIT that goes straight to controller not adding a field ? look up

Comment: I can no understand your English. please reword your question

Comment: look here; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53175644/persiscollection-in-entitytype-form that`s the problem and was before thats why i got so many issues,